# Insertion at end of linked list using recursion vs Iteration

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

The function to insert at end of linked list using recursion looks something like this

```
     // Main..
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
       cin>>x;
       insert(head,x);
     }

     void insert(struct node*&h,int x){
      if(h==NULL){
       h=new node(x);
       return;
      }
      insert(h->next,x);
     }
```

But if I am doing same with iteration it doesn't work the same way,Its making only one node.

```
     void insert(struct node* &h,int x){
             if(h==NULL){
             h=new node(x);
             return;
            }
        struct node* go=h;
        while(go){     //At (go==NULL) it should point to next of last node
         go=go->next;   // I know it should be go->next!=NULL condition.
       }
         go=new node(x);//Assigning next of last to new node.
   }
```

I am having serious mental blockage.Can anyone please help why it doesn't work ? What should I do to make it work ?

Comment: `while(!go){` =>  `while(go){`

Comment: Recursion is a bad idea - leads to stackoverflow.

Comment: yes,changed but still nothing changed.Still only one element as output. @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: @EdHeal Yes,Ofcourse.But I am worried that I am essentially doing the same as of recursion but not getting all elements as output ? Why so ?

Comment: @EdHeal: double entendre :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Please enlighten me - Is _double entendre_ used in French the same way as in English?

Comment: it means 2 meanings if I'm not mistaken. In french it doesn't exist even if both words are french.

Comment: @jean-FrancoisFabre oui d'accord. Merci. Usually the second meaning has a sexual innuendo

Comment: @EdHeal actually the OP wanted to get rid of recursion. Strangely he writes better recursive programs than iterative ones! normally it's the other way round.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No I know how both works(iterative and recursive)but sometime I can't feel how everything works :/

Comment: @GeorgeMIT Ed is right, you should avoid recursion when it's not needed, like here. If you have, say 1 million elements an iterative process can stomach it (would be rather slow, but no problem), but with a recursive process, you're almost sure to blow up the stack.

Comment: Also consider that the processor will be able to pipe line stuff. See branch prediction etc.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Is there anyway I can run till go!=NULL and also do the same as we do when we go till 'go->next!=NULL' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you loop until `go` is not null. Okay, once fixed, you loop until `go` is null,

Then you just overwrite a null pointer by a `new`. But that doesn't link it to your existing list.

Do that instead:

```
void insert(struct node* &h,int x)
{
   if(h==NULL)
   {
     h=new node(x);
     return;
   }
   struct node* go=h;

   // move until last element
   while(go->next)
   { 
      go=go->next; 
   }
   // create a node at the end
   go->next=new node(x);//Assigning next of last to new node.
}
```

At first iteration, `go` is guaranteed to be non-null (checked by first `if` condition).
Just check for the first `next` element to be null, and insert your new node here.

Comment: What I am doing is going until the end i.e next of last node and point go which is temporary variable to it(to next of last node).Next of last is NULL so our temporary pointer to node(go) will also point to NULL and when we assign go=new node(x),this is making changes to temporary variable which is pointing to next of last not the next of last node.Thats why I always have one node.While in case of recursion I am passing next of last as pointer to reference thus changes get reflects to it even though we run till go==NULL am I right sir ?

Comment: Please have another bash at the indentation S'il vous plaît

Comment: @EdHeal d'accord pas de problème.

Comment: @GeorgeMIT exactly.